# Apache Camel Stateful Bean

Tags: apache-camel

Based on below example , how to make my **Add** bean as Stateful:

```
   from("direct:firstRoute")
        .bean(Add.class)
        .bean(Add.class,"setIntA(1)")
        .bean(Add.class,"setIntB(1)")
        .log("${body}")
        .setHeader(SpringWebserviceConstants.SPRING_WS_SOAP_ACTION,simple("http://tempuri.org/Add"))
        .to("spring-ws:http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx")
        .convertBodyTo(AddResponse.class)
        .log("${body}");
```

That mean first i need to create the bean then Calling the **setIntA** method then **setIntB** without loosing the value in each step .

Comment: Are you talking about that the bean is only shared for the same message, not for any concurrent messages, or any new messages being routed later? If so then that is not supported by Camel.

Comment: yes i am talking about the same message , how to save the value in same instance in each step .

Comment: Koptan you cannot do this in Camel as Claus has said.

Comment: You would need to create the bean and store it on the Camel Exchange property, and then you can only call this bean manually by getting the bean from the exchange property and calling it. So its like using a bean to call another bean, but that bean you find from the exchange property.